# Gaussian Process data errors

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, statistics, standard-deviation, gaussian-process

How can I insert **error array** at `fitrgp` function of **matlab** to do **Gaussian Proccess Regression**? I have an **array** `x`, other **array** `y` and the standard deviation **array** `delta_y` associated to `y`.

With only `x` and `y`, I could use `gprMdl = fitrgp(x, y)`, but how can I add `delta_y` as the `errorbar` of `y`?